# Fluentd: Multiple formats in one match

Tags: match, fluent, fluentd

I'm new to Fluentd. I have one problem regarding the `<match>` tag and its format. For example

- Our system returns 2 different formats: **format1**, and **format2** at the same tag: **tag**
- Using fluent.conf we are able to catch the provided tag but we are unable to separate those two formats

I tried the [fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser](https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser) but it does not allow me to add the prefixes.

```
<match tag>
    @type parser
    format multi

    <pattern>
         format format1
         add_prefix pattern1
         ... 
    </pattern> 

    <pattern>
         format format2
         add_prefix pattern2
         ... 
    </pattern>
</match>
```

Is there any work-around solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer in [this Google Groups conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fluentd/aKZ1YfxoNJI) has a solution:

Specifically (incase the link doesn't work and to save time for those less interested):

For your purpose, you can use `copy` plugin. Copy the entire message, and then filter like:

```
<match tag>
  type copy
  <store>
    type grep
    input_key format_type
    regexp pattern1
    add_tag_prefix pattern1
  </store>
  <store>
    type grep
    input_key format_type
    regexp pattern2
    add_tag_prefix pattern2
  </store>
</match>
<match pattern1.tag>
</match>
<match pattern2.tag>
</match>
```

The `input_key` needs to be the key to run the regexp against.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'rewrite_tag_filter'

https://docs.fluentd.org/output/rewrite_tag_filter#configuration-example